# Enable syntax highlighting for code

Tags: feature-request, formatting

It would be nice to have syntax highlightin [in the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) that StackOverflow does.

As far as I could see, right now we do not have support for highlighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your question. Unfortunately syntax highlighting is not enabled by default when a site is in beta.

Since we are a site that does not deal primarily with programming languages, we may not need this functionality very often. However, it is certainly something that will be kept in mind should we ever graduate from beta.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. However, the Pi is also meant to be a device for learning to program. So I think we will see some snippets of code here. Also bash scripts, and config files might be more readable when using syntax highlighting.

Comment: If this post gets some more backing then I'll have a word :)

Comment: @Jivings: +1 for highlighting.