# Should we have syntax highlighting?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

This [has been asked before](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/379/5538), when we were still in beta.

Now we've graduated and everything looks all spiffy, I thought it would be nice to have syntax highlighting. As Jivings points out in the previous thread, we are primarily not a programming site, but on the other hand, we do get a decent amount of relevant snippets, mostly python, but also some C, C# (e.g., Windows IoT) and the occasional bit of shell.

I'm someone who looks at unhighlighted code and goes, "What? I have to read that without *colors*?".  Although it would not make a huge difference to the stuff we have around here, one useful thing it does do is set off comments, as in this example:

[Optimize portion of code for similar event callbacks in RPi.GPIO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33849527/1151724)

That person did not make an effort to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), which is perhaps why there's not an answer -- but it at least serves as an example here.

Highlighting is set on a per tag basis, so if you want to use it, make sure the appropriate tag is on the question. It should then apply to the answers as well, or, as per [the formatting tips](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting),<sup>1</sup>, you can provide a direct per snippet hint, e.g. in answers where you have a solution involving code but adding the tag would not be appropriate to the question (or you don't have the rep to do so).  For example:

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->

    vector<foo> bar;
```

Notice here the `<!--` line is **not indented**.  There also needs to be a blank line before and after it.  If you have several snippets using the same language, use `language-all:` and it will apply to everything after that.

Presuming we do want it, the floor is open for suggestions about which tags would be appropriate and what language would be suggested for them.  This can be set (by moderators) once enabled on an ongoing basis.

---

<sup>1. An observation, now that this has been enabled: It seems you need to use `lang-foo`, not just `foo`.  There's a bit of a list on the [Google Prettify repo page](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), but e.g., for shell/bash use `lang-bsh`. Defaults should be shown on in tag wiki, and if you have any suggestions leave a comment here.</sup>

Comment: I would be in favor of this. Off the top of my head I would add HTML, node.js and JS to the list of tags.

Comment: @SteveRobillard No python?

Comment: @Jivings goldilocks already mentioned python and C above

Comment: I managed to get formatting working [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38439/how-to-run-a-python-script-on-a-raspberry-pi-via-webserver/38441#38441), possibly by manually tagging it. Big thing on MetaSE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: @Wilf It was enabled today; anything tagged python should be auto..have a look in chat too for some caveats.

Answer (score 10):

**Yeah! Sure, what are we waiting for?**

I completely subscribe to this notion of yours: "What? I have to read that without *colors*?" And I also take it that the feature is implemented yet (as working on SO), so the workload to get it running here is small?

Comment: Apparently it uses Google Prettify client side, so I don't think it is any added load for the servers either.  *However*, it's ultimately not up to me, and whether someone who can wants to bother *may* depend on the response here ("Your community doesn't seem to care, and it's not strictly necessary, so...")

Comment: Ah, well, I mean the workload for the mods, @goldilocks, to make it work. I have all confidence that the servers can handle it.

Comment: +1 It's 2015, reading code in monochrome is just barbaric :P

Comment: @Jacobm001 Ok looks like it is done!

Answer (score 3):

We have turned on the site setting to allow for formatted code blocks. There is no default syntax, so you'll need to figure out what tags need to have prettified code blocks.

Comment: Seems to be working -- thanks much!

Comment: @Ghanima You can check [this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) to see how you can force syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yepp, thanks. I took it to chat.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]? :)

Comment: @Seth status added

Answer (score 2):

Seems self evident to me. I have been using syntax highlighting for 30 years.

I just tried adding `<!-- language: lang-bsh -->` but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: If you include a link to the post I can demonstrate.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5431/8697  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28087/8697

Comment: It was just a matter of adding a blank line *before* the `language:` line.  Another fenickity mechanism with overly vague documentation.  I also added `-all` on the second one so it covers subsequent snippets in the same post.  I'll edit an example into my OP.